Was the full diary of Jiro Horikoshi ever published?
Jiro Horikoshi, the constructor of A6M "Zero", was one of the most prominent Japan's aeronautical engineers immediately before and during WWII, his life being dramatized in a (relatively) recent Hayao Miyazaki's anime "The Wind Rises". In the accompanying materials to the film, Miyazaki constantly references a quote from Jiro Horikoshi's diary, the same quote being present on the English Wikipedia page dedicated to the man. However, I wasn't able to find anything but a few excerpts from this diary, covering exclusively the last 9 months of Japan's participation in WWII (the excerpts can be found in the last chapter of "Zero: The Story of Japan's Air War in the Pacific - As Seen by the Enemy", 2002, which is a slightly updated version of the 1956 book "Zero!"). I also wasn't able to find a dedicated biography of Jiro that would be longer than several A4 pages, besides, different accounts of his life contradict one another. From this stem my following questions:

Was the full diary of Jiro Horikoshi ever published?
Is there a book-length biography of Jiro in any language? Or at least some biography that is substantially more complete than the one found on Wikipedia.


Also posted on Anime.SE: https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/69146/2516

"His memoir regarding the development of the Zero was published in Japan in 1970, and was translated by the University of Washington Press as Eagles of Mitsubishi: The Story of the Zero Fighter, which was published in English in 1981." I can't seem to find any biography, autobiography, or diary to his name ad-hoc.

A full copy of the English translation cited in Wikipedia is on the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/eaglesofmitsubis0000hori

@DevSolar, the book "Eagles of Mitsubishi" does indeed contain a slightly more complete biography of Jiro than the Wikipedia article, but it is still very brief.

Well, even if the man did write a diary with any regularity, that does not mean it will be put into print, or in any way be made available. Or, even, preserved for posterity...
